# In an Android application,can more than one Main Activity exist

Tags: android, android-manifest, main-activity

I hope someone will help. In Android manifest file, can we specify more than one activity as the main activity?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. But you should define one as default by `CATEGORY_DEFAULT`.  Without default main activity if you have two activities, Android Market do not know what activity to start.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".FirstMainActivity"
        android:label="First Activity"
        android:icon="@drawable/first_icon">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SecondMainActivity"
        android:label="Second Activity"
        android:icon="@drawable/second_icon">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You have to set `action=MAIN` and `category=LAUNCHER` to be your entry point showed in launcher.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can have more than one `main` activity and you can have multiple `launcher` activities but if you do so, you will see as many icons in the applications drawer.

Answer (score 0):

If you think you have several entry points in your application then why not?